# How to successfully write a foreach $key=>$var to a textfile

Tags: php

I am new to both PHP and understanding GET/POST. I am using a postbackurl to this phpfile and trying to write GET/POST information to a text file. It's not working and I was hoping someone could point out my likely obvious error to me. Below is the code.

```php
$postback_data = $_REQUEST;

    foreach($postback_data as $key=>$var)
    {
        $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $output = $key . ' : ' . $val ."\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $output);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
```

Comment: I would open / close the file handle **outside** the loop as each iteration will replace the entire file because you are only _writing_ and not _appending_

Comment: _"It's not working"_  can you describe _how_ it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

There are two misconceptions in your code:

1. You are opening a file, write to it and close it for each `$key=>$var` in `$postback_data` which is highly ineffective. You should open it once before the loop and close it after completion of the loop.
2. You are *writing* to a file instead of *appending*. Check the modes for [fopen()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Here is the code that might do what you desire:

```
$postback_data = $_REQUEST;

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
foreach($postback_data as $key=>$var) {
  $output = $key . ' : ' . $val ."\n";
  fwrite($myfile, $output);
}
fclose($myfile);
```

If you wish to create a new file for each request, use the `"w"` mode on `fopen()`. Use `"a"` if you want to append every new request’s POST data to the same file.

Comment: From the `fopen()` manual ~ _"For portability, it is strongly recommended that you always use the `'b'` flag when opening files with **fopen()**."_

Answer (score 0):

Place fopen and fclose outside the loop or use fopen('file.txt', a) instead. fopen('file.txt', w) resets the files and overwrites everything.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just saving that information into a file to see it and format is not so important, you can achieve that by using a few built-in functions. You don't need to iterate all over the list using `foreach`:

```
$post = var_export($_REQUEST, true);
file_put_contents('newfile.txt', $post);
```

Beware: `$_REQUEST` also contains `$_COOKIE` data besides `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

> `var_export` here returns string representation of given variable. If you the omit second argument `true`, it directly prints it.

If your goal is improving your skills, here is the correct version of your code with some notes:

```
// prefer camelCase for variable names rather than under_scores
$postbackData = $_REQUEST;

// Open the resource before (outside) the loop
$handle = fopen('newfile.txt', 'w');
if($handle === false) {
    // Avoid inline die/exit usage, prefer exceptions and single quotes
    throw new \RuntimeException('File could not open for writing!');
}

// Stick with PSR-2 or other well-known standard when writing code
foreach($postbackData as $key => $value) {
    // The PHP_EOL constant is always better than escaped new line characters
    $output = $key . ' : ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($handle, $output);
}

// Close the resource after the loop
fclose($handle);
```

And don't forget to call your file using some test data in your querystring such as: http://localhost/postback.php?bar=baz Otherwise, both `$_RQUEST` and the contents of the file would be empty since there is nothing to show.

Good luck and welcome to stack overflow!